# GetxBuilder not working with listviewbuilder

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I am working on app where I have to set values to the all textFields on single button click. I have done that. I have used GetX for performing that task. When I update the values it updated the values in List datatype but the updated value is not being shown on the User Interface.

*first image code*

```
 GetBuilder<LabourBulkController>(builder: (dx) {
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: dx.workersList.length,
                  physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return Card(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Column(children: [
                          Row(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              const SizedBox(
                                width: 10,
                                height: 50,
                              ),
                              const Icon(FeatherIcons.user),
                              const SizedBox(
                                width: 20,
                              ),
                              Text(
                                "${dx.workersList[index]['name']}",
                                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          TextFormField(
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                                hintText: "Wages",
                                prefixIcon: Icon(
                                  Icons.wallet,
                                  color: Colors.blue,
                                )),
                            initialValue:
                                dx.workersList[index]['amount'].toString(),
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              _bulkController.workersList[index]['amount'] =
                                  value;
                            },
                          )
                        ]),
                      ),
                    );
                  });
            }),
```

**second image code**

```
 FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                print(_bulkController.workersList);
              },
              child: const Icon(Icons.cloud_upload)),
```

**controller**

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class LabourBulkController extends GetxController {
  RxList workersList = [].obs;
  RxBool loading = false.obs;
  getActiveLabours() async {
    loading.value = true;
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var token = prefs.getString("token");
    var response = await http.get(
        Uri.parse("http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/supervisor/active/labours"),
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
        });
    var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
    workersList.clear();
    for (var i = 0; i < data['data'].length; i++) {
      Map customerData = {
        "id": data['data'][i]['worker_id'],
        "name": data['data'][i]['worker_name'],
        "amount": 0,
      };
      workersList.add(customerData);
    }
    loading.value = false;
    update();
  }

  assignAtOnce(String amount) {
    loading.value = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < workersList.length; i++) {
      workersList[i]['amount'] = amount;
      loading.value = false;
    }
    update();
  }
}
```

**Screenshot**
[image]

[image]

Comment: transfer the update(); or Add another update(); inside the loop below on the  **workersList.add(customerData);** but

Comment: Okay Sir...no effect on it sir.

Comment: Which one of this need to show the user when it change the first image ? or second?

Comment: If i change something on the second image it should reflect on the first.

Comment: So its on the assignAtOnce() try again to put update() below  workersList[i]['amount'] = amount; and  loading.value = false;

Comment: ` assignAtOnce(String amount) {
    loading.value = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < workersList.length; i++) {
      workersList[i]['amount'] = amount;
      loading.value = false;
    }
    update();
  }` not working sir...but the updated data is showing in the debug console.

Comment: @ArbiterChil Sir the code is working properly i change the name but i am not changing the value inside TextField. that is the only problem I did this ```assignAtOnce(String amount) {
    for (var i = 0; i < workersList.length; i++) {
      workersList[i]['name'] = amount;
    }
    print(workersList);
    update();
  }``` it worked